# How to activate click option on a table-responsive column in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a page where I set the dataTable content in the div using the following code:

```
$('#' + divid + '-data')[0].innerHTML = data.TableContent;
```

I get the table content from a different method. Here is my `TableContent`:

```
<table class="table-responsive dataTable table-striped" id="51">
   <tr>
      <td class="details-control"></td>
      <td>Hi</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

On the page, when I tried to display an alert message on click on table-responsive column, nothing happens.

```
$("td.details-control").on("click", function(e) {
   alert("hi");
});
```

I also tried:

```
document.getElementById("#table-51").on("click", "tr td.details-control", function () {
                alert("hi");
            });
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
$("td.details-control").click(function(){
  alert("Hi");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-responsive dataTable table-striped" id="51">
   <tr>
      <td class="details-control">Show alert</td>
      <td>Hi</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Should I create a function showAlert() and call alert message?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
   <table class="table-responsive dataTable table-striped" id="51">
       <tr>
      <td class="details-control"></td>
      <td onclick="alert('hi')">Hi</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to overcomplicate this issue; keep it simple! You miss something to click on (empty `<td>`) and the use of a native DOM method along with a jQuery delegated event handler will never work.

```js
var data = { TableContent: `<table class="table-responsive dataTable table-striped" id="51">
   <tr>
      <td class="details-control">click me</td>
      <td>Hi</td>
   </tr>
</table>`
}

$('#sample')[0].innerHTML = data.TableContent;

$('#sample').on('click', 'td.details-control', function(e) {
   alert("hi");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample"></div>
```